# How to obtain the difference of values of two specific dates with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this data in a DataFrame. I want to know how I can get the difference between values of two specific dates, I am kind of new with Pandas. I want to store that difference in a variable.

```
         date  value
0  2008-03-01   35.4
1  2008-06-01   37.5
2  2008-09-01   42.7
3  2008-12-01   47.6
4  2009-03-01   50.1
5  2009-06-01   54.3
6  2009-09-01   55.8
7  2009-12-01   60.5
8  2010-03-01   64.6
9  2010-06-01   66.7
```

Comment: .iloc `df.iloc[0,1]-df.iloc[-1,1]`

Comment: @Wen Nice, write an answer for it!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ man it is definitely a dup :-), since it is very basic ...I can not find the dup question ,,,

Comment: Yes, it is. @OP, see second answer in the dupe, and change `/` to `-`

Comment: Hi, I made some changes to the question. It is simple, I realize I need to know the difference of the values in two specific dates